# UIAlertView to delete core data entity

Tags: core-data, uialertview

I'm trying to use an alertView to warn users that they are about to delete an object.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Caution!"
                                                    message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this truck?"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"NO"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}   }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [truckTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    Truck *truck = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [moc deleteObject:truck];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![moc save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
else    {
}}
```

The alert view appears correctly, if I tap "NO" is disappears and all is well.  If I tap "YES", the app crashes with no log report, just EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  From what I have researched, it's possible that the alertView is releasing before deleting the object?  Is this right?  If so, then how to I retain the alertView until after the delete has processed?
thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is caused because `[truckTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` is nil. And because of this, truck will be nil too. And when you try to delete a "nil object" `deleteObject:` will throw an exception

You should save the indexPath of the cell you want to delete as an instance variable.

Often `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` comes from accessing a released object, but not this time. It's ok to release the alert after you've showed it.

Comment: Thanks @fluchtpunkt.  I'm not sure I follow "save the indexPath of the cell as an ivar".  Why does the delete code work fine until I try to implement the alertView?

Comment: without the alert did you use `[truckTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` too? A delete with `indexPathForSelectedRow` will only work when you select the exact same cell before you delete it.

Comment: It could be that the row is getting unselected when the table view loses focus upon showing the alert view. I would set a breakpoint in the debugger at the line [NSIndexPath *indexPath = [truckTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]; to see if this variable is nil.

Comment: No, I didn't use `indexPathForSelectedRow` before I tried the alertView.  So somehow I need to "grab" the object of the selectedRow as the alertView is being called?

Comment: In tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: you could save off the indexPath being passed as a parameter or save off the corresponding object and then use that when you go to delete it.

Comment: as I said, save the indexPath you get from `tableView:commitEditingStyle:editingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` as an instance variable and use it in the alert delegate. There is no selection if you delete a cell, and therefor indexPathForSelectedRow is nil.

Comment: I do see that the "delete" button disappears when the alertView appears.  Does that mean the row is getting unselected?  What condition would I put on the breakpoint to check if *indexPath is nil?

Comment: Thanks so much for our help!  Would either of you have an example of how to save that indexPath as an ivar?

Comment: In your class header file in the interface section

Comment: In your class header file in the interface section add an instance variable NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndexPath. Make it a property and then synthesize it in your implementation file (also remember to release it in the dealloc method!). Then in  tableView:commitEditingStyle:editingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: just set it self.selectedRowIndexPath = indexPath, then use it in your deletion code.

Comment: Perfect!  worked beautifully!  Thanks @Greg C and @fluchtpunkt!